# Function Return HTML

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have function who return html

```
renderSuggestion(suggestion) {
    const query = this.query;

    if (suggestion.name === "hotels") {
        const image = suggestion.item;
        return this.$createElement('div', image.title);
    } else {
        let str = suggestion.item.name;
        let substr = query;
        return this.$createElement('div', str.replace(substr, `<b>${substr}</b>`));

    }
},
```

But`<b>` element not render in browser as html element. Its display like string...
How I display this `<b>` element?

Tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also create a component and use [v-html](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML) to render the output.

Declare props for your inputs:

```
export default {
  props: {
    suggestion: Object,
    query: String
  }
};
```

And use a template that uses your logic in the `template` part

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <div v-if="suggestion.name === 'hotels'">{{suggestion.item.title}}</div>
    <div v-else>
      <div v-html="suggestion.item.name.replace(this.query, `<b>${this.query}</b>`)"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

This allows for greater flexibility when using more complex layouts.

A working example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-panini-1j727)

Answer (score 2):

That is because when you provide a string as the second argument of `createElement`, VueJS actually inserts the string as a text node (hence your HTML tags will appear as-is). What you want is actually to [use a data object as the second argument](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#The-Data-Object-In-Depth), which give you finer control over the properties of the created element:

```
this.$createElement('div', {
    domProps: {
        innerHHTML:  str.replace(substr, `<b>${substr}</b>`)
    }
});
```

Of course, when you are using `innerHTML`, use it with caution and never insert user-provided HTML, to avoid XSS attacks.

Comment: Completely agree with the caution about user-provided HTML. I'll add that if it's a user-provided string, you *must* assume the string contains HTML. Display as a string or sanitize thoroughly!

Answer (score 0):

Provide more detail(possibly a picture) of how it's not showing. Consider using a custom CSS class to see the div and what's happening to it.

```
bold {
    border-style: black;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

then just use the "bold" class instead of "b".